# control keys produce ascii output in Vi insert mode

Tags: vim

When I enter  mode in vim, all control keys (like arrow keys, delete keys etc.) produce characters instead of expected control behaviour. How can I change this? Thanks :)

Comment: Works for me. Can you post the contents of /etc/vim/usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/debian.vim, /etc/vim/vimrc, and if present ~/.vimrc? You can use a link to http://paste.ubuntu.com instead of pasting everything into your question.

Comment: create a blank ~/.vimrc and restart vim. does that help?

Comment: Lol, I only had Vi and just installed Vim. Now it works perfectly.. don't know if there is still something to post or to be solved now :s thanks for the help :)

Comment: Heh, don't worry - such things happen! :) IIRC you can close/delete your own questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing `vim`, instead. This is the default behavior of `vi`. If you have `vim` installed, the best way to get vim behavior is to `touch .vimrc` in your home directory.

Comment: Now that's a revelation. I had the same problem, and after reading this answer, I checked whether on my system it's vi or vim by starting vi with no filename given. The welcome screen clearly stated "vi improved". I then found out that this is actually from the package "vim-tiny". After installing vim everything works as expected. However I don't understand how Ubuntu cannot provide a properly working version of vim in the default install. :-(

Comment: @Axel vim may also behave this way. I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This may happen if

1. you're actually using old vi not vim
2. vim doesn't recognize or know your terminal type.  in the shell you invoked vi from, type

   ```
   echo $TERM
   ```